# Ping reports name resolution failure with foo.local, but not with foo, but only for certain machines

Tags: windows, networking, dns, ping

We'll call my domain example.com. The DC (running Windows Server 2008) acts as a DNS server, and there are two machines of interest, which I'll call foo and bar. foo and bar are both type A in the same zone.

From an unrelated client machine on the domain, I can:

`ping foo`
`ping bar`
`ping foo.example.com`
`ping bar.example.com`
`ping bar.local`

But `ping foo.local` fails with an error message about not being able to resolve the hostname.

There are no conflicting entries in the host file and this can be replicated on any machine in the domain.

So, my question is basically why does `bar.local` work, but not `foo.local`? As far as I can tell, there's no difference between `foo` and `bar`'s configuration on the DNS server, so I would think that they'd both show the same behavior (either both or neither respond to .local).

I don't have much networking knowledge, so I really have no idea what's going on. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is `foo` on a different IP subnet or different Ethernet LAN from the "unrelated client machine"?

Comment: No. All machines are on the same subnet and LAN.

Comment: @FrankThomas That's not quite right. For some reason Microsoft didn't like Bonjour (a.k.a. mDNS, IETF ZeroConf) in the early days, so they created their own proprietary nonstandard thing called "Link Local Multicast Name Resolution" (LLMNR), and used that for resolving .local names. Now in Windows 10, Microsoft has quietly, finally added real ZeroConf support, but Windows Server 2008 would've used LLMNR exclusively (unless you'd installed something like Apple's Bonjour Print Services for Windows).

Comment: @KevinMills Are any of the machines on Wi-Fi?

Comment: What's the exact error `Ping foo.local` is giving you?  Does `nslookup foo.local` work as expected?

Comment: @Spiff Neither `foo` or `bar`, nor any of the other machines attached to the domain I've tried pinging from are connected to wi-fi.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Ping says "Ping request could not find host foo.local. Please check the name and try again."

Comment: nslookup fails for both `foo.local` and `bar.local` (but succeeds for `foo` and `bar`) with error message "UnKnown can't find foo.local: Non-existent domain".

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I'm not sure nslookup ever uses the LLMNR subsystem. I'm pretty sure it crafts its own DNS queries and sends them directly to the DNS server rather than calling Windows APIs for name resolution services.

Comment: @KevinMills Thanks for your answers. LLMNR can fail when multicasts fail, so I was looking for reasons multicast could be failing on your network; multicast would fail between broadcast domains (Ethernet LANs), and it often fails on Wi-Fi due to buggy Wi-Fi implementations. You might still want to see if multicast is working in both directions between your "unrelated client machine" and foo. I suspect that LLMNR requests and responses aren't successfully getting between those two machines.